# How to pause VideoStream while holding down a key? Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, keypress, video-capture, pause

I am trying to create a webcam-videostream for a image processing project, and I want a way to pause the stream (because it is really useful for checking values, masks, et cetera)
I did found an easy way using time.sleep() to pause for a set amount, but it is not really what I wanted.

What I really want is a way to pause the stream when I press SPACE, and unpause when I release it. 
Holding down a key seems to me as the easiest option, because it would just mean checking if a button is being pressed at the start of a frame, and if it is, just skip that particular frame. However, the code I have tried here (using continue to skip the frame) does not work.

Any suggestions?

```
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import imutils
import time
import cv2

vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()

while True:
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == ord("q"): break # quitting when q is pressed
    # if key == ord(" "): time.sleep(5)
    if key == ord(" "): continue

    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)

    if frame is None:
        print("Oops, something went wrong")
        break

    # Image processing over here

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)  

vs.stop()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Also, if anyone has any other tips or suggestions for my code, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the space key as a switch instead of continuously pressing it. Press it once to stop and press again to start and so on. For this simply use a flag variable that changes value whenever the space key is pressed. I used this code and it worked:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
flag = True
while(True):
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord(' '):
        flag = not(flag)
        print(flag)
        # Capture frame-by-frame
    if flag == True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if frame is None:
            break
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        continue

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

EDIT (for the comment)

I did some testing to check the values obtained by continuously pressing the space button with this code:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    print(key)
    if key == ord(' '):
        continue
    elif key != ord('q'):
        # Capture frame-by-frame
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if frame is None:
            break
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    else:
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, even after continuously pressing the space key the values printed were

```
.
.
.
255
32
255
32
255
255
32
32
255
32
255
113
```

where 255 stands for blank, 32 for space and 113 for 'q'. I am sorry but I don't the reason this is happening but this needs to be solved else it won't work holding down the space key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Using space as a flag solved my problem. However, I am still curious: Is there no way to check if a button is being pressed? Do you always need to do the pressed-released thing? It works, but it seems to me as quite elaborate as so much extra code is needed.